# maybe final obstacle for my couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

Using Moxi on client side is really complicated i think

I got moxi running with this command

./moxi -vvv -p 11311
and checked /etc/init.d/moxi-server status and returned moxi server is running

I've made a test code with libcouchbase
create instance with (127.0.0.1:11311 as host, NULL as rest of parameters)
it seems Instance is created and call back is set normally. However, the process seeems stuck in connecting. I think this is because I've not set correct moxi setting (making moxi to see my couchbase cluster).

Can you please explain this client moxi setting procedure in deep? manual is not really helping atm.

Moxi Screen : 
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 52: drive_machine conn_listening
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.403) <53 new auto-negotiating client connection
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (cproxy.c.524) <53 assigning to first bucket
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_new_cmd
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.670) 53: going from conn_new_cmd to conn_waiting
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_waiting
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.670) 53: going from conn_waiting to conn_read
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_read
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.670) 53: going from conn_read to conn_parse_cmd
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_parse_cmd
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3125) 53: Client using the proxy-upstream-ascii protocol
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (cproxy_protocol_a.c.34) <53 cproxy_process_upstream_ascii GET /pools/default/bucketsStreaming/test HTTP/1.1
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.821) >53 ERROR
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.670) 53: going from conn_parse_cmd to conn_write
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_write
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_write
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.670) 53: going from conn_write to conn_new_cmd
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_new_cmd
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.670) 53: going from conn_new_cmd to conn_parse_cmd
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_parse_cmd
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (cproxy_protocol_a.c.34) <53 cproxy_process_upstream_ascii
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.821) >53 ERROR
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.670) 53: going from conn_parse_cmd to conn_write
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_write
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_write
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.670) 53: going from conn_write to conn_new_cmd
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_new_cmd
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.670) 53: going from conn_new_cmd to conn_waiting
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.3457) 53: drive_machine conn_waiting
2012-03-28 11:41:46: (memcached.c.670) 53: going from conn_waiting to conn_read

Comment: For anyone following along at home, the relevant manual section is here: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/moxi-manual-1.8/moxi-standalone.html As far as being able to help with this particular issue, maybe you can tell us more about your deployment environment?

Answer (score 1):

With 2.0, we have added a lot more smart client support, so there is less and less reason to use Moxi. Have a look and see if there is an SDK for your development environment here:

http://www.couchbase.com/develop

Using the smart client SDKs will be a lot simpler, as well as more performant.